# Map a Sitecore visitor to a custom Channel

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have some affiliate sites, which link to my Sitecore website.

I created a custom Channel for these affiliate sites. What I want to do is map those visitors to the custom Channel, based on the Referred HTTP header, so I can personalise components based on the Channel.

Sitecore doesn't document this portion very well in my opinion, and I can't find much on the internet either.

How do I do this? 
Do I need program my own Pipeline, or is this default functionality in Sitecore?

**EDIT:**
There should be a way to this with `interactionChannelMappings`
Here is some xml from the `Sitecore.Social.config` file

```xml
 <interactionChannelMappings>
     <!-- 41-91-05: Online/Social Community/Facebook Social Community -->
     <channel channelId="{A9F2D058-95A5-4461-B1E5-8502D2303AF1}">
        <!-- Facebook -->
        <channelMapping urlReferrerHost="www.facebook.com" />
        <!-- Facebook for mobile -->
        <channelMapping urlReferrerHost="m.facebook.com" />
        <!-- Facebook's Link Shim -->
        <channelMapping urlReferrerHost="l.facebook.com" />
        <!-- Facebook's Link Shim for mobile -->
        <channelMapping urlReferrerHost="lm.facebook.com" />
     </channel>  
 </interactionChannelMappings>
```

It looks like wildcards. But where exactly do I put this (I don't want it in the `Sitecore.Social.config` file. And what other code do I need? I can't find any documentation on the Sitecore website other than [this](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/marketing_operations/channels/map_traffic_types_to_channels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:
Create own Channel Item, for example:

`/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Taxonomies/Channel/Online/Affiliates/Site2`

Create own Traffictype:

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Traffic Type/Affiliate`

[Add the channel mapping](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/marketing_operations/channels/map_traffic_types_to_channels) to Sitecore.Analytics.Compatibility.config:

```xml
<add trafficType="TRAFFIC-ID" channel="{CHANNEL-ITEM-GUID}" />
```

create a new .config with:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <social>
      <interactionChannelMappings>
        <channel channelId="{CHANNEL-ITEM-GUID}">
          <!-- affiliate wildcards -->
          <channelMapping urlReferrerHost="site2.com" />
        </channel>
      </interactionChannelMappings>
    </social>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Visits coming from site2.com should now be automatically be mapped to the newly created custom channel

Answer (score 1):

One way to map visits to channels is with a campaign, but that would require the link to include a campaign identifier.

Another way to do this would be to use the API to set the ChannelId of the current interaction. This can be done in a pipeline as you already mentioned to make sure it is done on every request (first request of the session is enough actually).

There might be other ways as well though...

Edit for using the API: Create a class like this and add it in the CreateVisit pipeline after the default SetChannel (use a config patch).

```cs
public class SetChannel : CreateVisitProcessor
{
    public override void Process(CreateVisitArgs args)
    {
      Guid channelID = ... // Get your channel ID
      args.Interaction.ChannelId = channelID;
    }
}
```

Edit2 : the interactionChannelMappings could indeed be an option. Never tried that myself but it should be fairly easy to add your channel(s) and their mappings there by using a config patch. When looking at the code that is performed when reading that config, it should do what you want (i.e. set the channel based on the referrer). So no custom code required. 
More info on config patching can be found here: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/all-about-web-config-include-files-with-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms. If in doubt, check the result with `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`.

Comment: Could you help me a bit in the right direction? I found this blog: http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.nl/2015/08/sitecore-pipelines-createvisit.html

Do I need to inherit from the SetChannel class or approach this differently?

Comment: Thanks, this will probably work. But I think there is a 3rd option to map the visitor to a channel. I will update my question

Comment: added some info on interactionChannelMappings